# Angular - IE not responding issue when binding huge data

Tags: angular, typescript, internet-explorer, observable, subscription

My service is returning more than 7000 records when I bind the response to component variable then the screen goes to not responding mode. This is only specific to IE. Similarly i have 3 dropdowns in the UI. I have tried resolver as well but didn't work for me. Screen goes to not responding when the service call completed.

**Component.ts**

```
 this._myservice.getData(this.param1).subscribe(response => {this.Capabilities = response.json()});
```

**Component.html**

```
     <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li *ngFor="let capability of Capabilities;trackBy:capability?.Name" id="{{capability.Id}}">

      <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="{{capability.Id}}">{{capability.Name}}</a>
       </li>
    </ul>
```

Comment: Can you please inform us which IE version you are using for making this test? I suggest you to try to bind small amount of data at a time may help to avoid the issue. You can try to fetch your data multiple times to fetch all the necessary data. Also you can try to refer this link may give you information about improving the performance of an Angular app. Ref. https://github.com/mgechev/angular-performance-checklist

Comment: We are using IE 11

Comment: Did you test with small amount of records? If yes, can you please inform us your testing results? Further, Did you try to optimize your Angular code for better performance?

Comment: I tested with some small amount of records it was working fine. If you provide some Angular optimization then it would be great.

Comment: You can refer these sites my give you steps to optimize the performance of Angular app. https://itnext.io/how-to-optimize-angular-applications-99bfab0f0b7c and https://medium.com/@spp020/44-quick-tips-to-fine-tune-angular-performance-9f5768f5d945 and https://angular-guru.com/blog/angular-performance-tips

Answer (score 0):

7000 records!!!
It's big amount of records!!!
Whit your code you try to add in the dom all your records at the same time:

```
<li *ngFor="let capability of Capabilities;trackBy:capability?.Name" id="{{capability.Id}}">
```

Therefore, your browser will display 7000 items in a raw (big memory consumption).

for sutch amount of records, I think that it is better to go through "virtual scroll" see:
https://material.angular.io/cdk/scrolling/overview

https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/how-to-use-virtual-scrolling-using-angular-7-cdk-9802110111fa

and a demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-demo-virtual-scroll?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

=> If you press F12 in the demo, you'll see that only few elements are displayed in the app-virtual-scroll=> better perfromances